# how do i echo an image in another page based on its id?

Tags: php, html

How do I get my image id to be echoed in another page?

Page Portfolio:

[ image one ]

[ image two ]

---

[ image one ] has id of image1. When clicking on image1, it will direct to a new page to display in a larger size.

so far, here is my code.

**Page Portfolio**

```
<a href="view.php?id=image1"><img src="image1.jpg"/></a>
<a href="view.php?id=image2"><img src="image2.jpg"/></a>
```

**view.php**

```
<?php $id=$_GET['id']; ?>

<?php if($id == 'image1'){
    echo '<img src="orange.jpg"/>';} ?>

<?php if($id == 'image2'){
    echo '<img src="milk.jpg"/>';} ?>
```

It is acceptable if I use this code for a few pictures, but I am going to use it for a lot of pictures. Any suggestion or tips? Is it possible to echo based on the id of the images?
Any help is appreciated. Thank you for your time.

I'm really sorry that I forgot to mention that I am not getting the image from database. Please take a look at the **view.php** I've edited above. I'm not sure if I explain myself clear enough.

Comment: Perhaps use a switch instead? Or if it's A LOT then perhaps create an' array with all the names / get the list of pics by checking the dir, and then store that in a array, and then use `in_array();` or something similar to check if the clicked image is valid / exists

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Epodax. I've never thought of using switch. I just want to know if this works using the code that is used to get picture from the database. Like this code:


`<img src="<?php if ($get_q['picture']!= ''){ echo "../upload_img/".$get_q['picture'];} ?>" alt="your image" id="upload-pic" />`

Which do you think is more suitable for a set of 50 images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php $id=$_GET['id']; 
 echo '<img src="'.$id.'.jpg"/>';

?>
```

Comment: this will not work, because in the html he is using <img src="somephp.php.."> and the php will print another <img src> so the php will be an html and not a img src

Comment: Actually it somehow gives me a rough idea. Thank you for the helpful tip :) @Arun Krish

Answer (score 1):

You CAN'T echo img src=... in the php because you already doing this in the original HTML as a source, you need to print the picture.

```
 //phpFile.php
 <?php echo "<img src..">;
```

will be parsed as an HTML document, so in the html

the source will be an html document and NOT an Image.

you need to replace img to iframe or

use this in the php

```
$file = $_GET['id']; //or full path to file
$type = 'image/jpeg';
header('Content-Type:'.$type);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

Comment: Hello @Daniel Krom and thank you for your reply. It took me a long time to digest what you suggested. Just tried your code but it did not work. I forgot to mention that I do not get the image from the database. Is that the reason why I failed?

Comment: You need to write full file path, create it by id and also recommnded to add file_exists validation

Answer (score 1):

You could use the GET value as part of the `src` attribute, like so:

```
<?php
echo '<img src="' . $_GET['id'] . '".jpg" />';
?>
```

But note that this requires every image to have the same jpeg extension.

Answer (score 1):

While it might be a bit overkill and the other answers having a more straight approach, I figured I'd give you this option as well. (This is for your `view.php` file of course :) )

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$validImages = array
(
    'image1.jpg',
    'image2.jpg',
    'image3.jpg'
);

if(in_array($id,$validImages)){
    <-- DISPLAY IMAGE HERE -->
}else{
    die('Invalid image');
}
```

And if you desire @Daniel Krom's edition with the header(); part it's just a simple matter of putting it inside of the `if(){}` clause instead of the `echo` :)

Comment: this will not work unless in the HTML he will change the img tag to iframe, because in the php he's already printing img src tag and many browsers will get it as an html document and not as an image source.it'll work if he'll change img tag to iframe

Comment: @DanielKrom I'm not really focusing on displaying the image, plenty of answers doing that all ready. I was trying to offer him a way to check the image requested before showing it :)

Comment: yea ok (: because the php file is the source, but nvm

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Epodax.Tried your code, but it didn't work.  I've edited my question. I'm sorry for the confusion. Is it because of I did not get the image from the database?

Comment: Where are the images located? In a folder? If so it's just a simple matter of using the correct path, if you store them in a database or something else, then yes you need to connect to it and fetch them.

Comment: They are all located in the same folder. @Epodax So does my code earlier close enough to the right answer?

Comment: It should be, although I'm not entirely sure what you are referring to. But your link to the image needs to contain the entire image path, for example: `/public/images/image1.jpg`

Comment: I'm sorry @Epodax, I think I didn't explain myself clear enough. I have succeeded on displaying the image in another page using the code in my question above. I wish there are simpler and shorter way to view the respected image according to the assigned id. I would probably use your switch method later if there isn't any other simpler ways to do so. >.< My friend told me it's not possible because the images are not stored in the database.

Comment: I don't get the whole urge about database, you don't need a database to display images,

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your suggestions! I manage to get it work using the following codes. :) - Nurul

**Page Portfolio**

```
<a href="view.php?id=image1"><img src="image1.jpg" id="image1"/></a>
<a href="view.php?id=image2"><img src="image2.jpg" id="image2"/></a>
```

**view.php**

```
<?php $id=$_GET['id']; ?>
<img src="<?php echo $id; ?>.jpg"/>
```

(if and only if the extension of all images are the same just like FDekker said.)